# SwiftUI: Custom color for navigationBarTitle?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to use a custom navigtionBarTitle color.
[I have tried to do the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qII1.png)

But the color doesn't change :(. I want to use a custom color and not an UIColor.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Check out this for customizing the navigationbar: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swiftui-customize-navigation-bar-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

try

```swift
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Hello World").foregroundColor(Color.red))
```